# What is a word for a person who stands up for their rights/doesn't give up/fights for what's right

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a book, and I need a name for a group of people who are standing up for what is right. At first I thought of calling them the Dreamers, but then I searched it up and dreamers meant *a person who dreams or is dreaming.
a person who is unpractical or idealistic.* It doesn't really suit what I am looking for. I'm wanting something more... heroic. Please answer quickly! Thank you!

Comment: Search synonyms for *hero* and then search individually for each of the terms.

Comment: activists, marchers, liberators, campaigners, (civil right) leaders, ..

Answer (score 1):

I found several terms, hope they were useful:

**Advocates**

A definition of *advocate* according to Merriam-Webster:

> one who defends or maintains a cause or proposal

**Proponents**

A definition of *proponent* according to Merriam-Webster:

> one who argues in favor of something

**Social Justice Warriors**

The definition of *social justice warrior* according to Google:

> a person who expresses or promotes socially progressive views

**Apostles**

A definition of *apostle* according to Merriam-Webster:

> a person who initiates a great moral reform or who first advocates an important belief or system

**Champions**

A definition of *champion* according to Merriam-Webster:

> one that does battle for another's rights or honor